# What are the security implications of the isEvalSupported option in PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

The [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library has an option [`isEvalSupported`](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/global.html#DocumentInitParameters), which is described as follows:

> (optional) Determines if we can eval strings as JS. Primarily used to
>   improve performance of font rendering, and when parsing PDF functions.
>   The default value is `true`.

This *sounds* like a bad idea for untrusted PDFs.  Does this have security implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially, there is a tiny possibility, but PDF only evals code it generates itself (not random JS script) -- so theoretically it's not really a concern. The PDF.js was reviewed multiple times for these usages. Keep in mind, it's a web application, and worse it can do is XSS attack.

If you serve untrusted PDFs in a PDF viewer and you are hosting at your location, it is better be located at different origin than your main app, www.example.org vs pdfviewer.example.org.